# XMPP offline message(s) received every time user logs in

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am working with `XMPP server`, backend enabled with BuddyCloud. Everything is working fine.
My only issue is, when someone sends me an offline message (means when I am offline), so when I logs in again and send my `Presence` all the offline message start receiving.

Scenario:

If I am offline, and someone sends me the message, I should not receive it and it happens correctly. And when I came online, I should receive that message. Which I receives and it is correct till this point.

Now when I come online any next time, I always receive that message, which I have received already. Tell me If I am still not clear with my issue.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean with "…when I was offline, either they are received or not"? If you are offline, the messages are not received (by the intended recipient).

Comment: If I am offline, and someone sends me the message I should not receive it and it happens correctly.
BUT when I came online, I receive that message. Which is correct till this point.
Now when I come online any next time, I always receive that message, which I have received already.

Tell me If I am still not clear with my issue.

Comment: You should edit that into your question.